# Mutex is not supported when compiling with /clr or clr:pure (cpprestsdk aka casablanca)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, clr, cpprest-sdk

I create a `CLR project` in `visual c++` with `64 bit` configuration, and try to use `cpprestsdk aka casablanca 64bit`.

But when I run the project, an error occured:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Timestamp, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>MyForm.cpp
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.13.26128\include\mutex(8): fatal error C1189: #error:  <mutex> is not supported when compiling with /clr or /clr:pure.
1>Testapi.cpp
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.13.26128\include\mutex(8): fatal error C1189: #error:  <mutex> is not supported when compiling with /clr or /clr:pure.
1>Generating Code...
1>Done building project "Timestamp.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Other error:

```
E2093   a local lambda is not allowed in a member function of a managed class   Timestamp   c:\Users\Laptop-attendance\source\repos\Timestamp\Timestamp\Testapi.h   97
```

The IDE shows an error about `'['` characters in the `.then` function like `.then([=](http_response response)`, which if you pointed it out, it says `"a local lambda is not allowed in a member function of a managed class"`

If I try the `cpprestsdk` in a `Windows Console Application` of Visual c++ with 64 bit configuration, it works fine.

I'm using visual studio 2017.

Do you think cpprestsdk cannot be used in CLR project of vc++?

Thanks.

Here's my code, and the code about cpprestsdk I just got it from its tutorial:

```
#ifndef TESTAPI_H
#define TESTAPI_H

#pragma once

#include <cpprest/http_client.h>
#include <cpprest/filestream.h>
#include <cpprest/json.h>

namespace Timestamp {

    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::ComponentModel;
    using namespace System::Collections;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    using namespace System::Data;
    using namespace System::Drawing;

    using namespace utility;                    // Common utilities like string conversions
    using namespace web;                        // Common features like URIs.
    using namespace web::http;                  // Common HTTP functionality
    using namespace web::http::client;          // HTTP client features
    using namespace concurrency::streams;       // Asynchronous streams

    /// <summary>
    /// Summary for Testapi
    /// </summary>
    public ref class Testapi : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
    public:
        Testapi(void)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //
            //TODO: Add the constructor code here
            //
        }

    protected:
        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        ~Testapi()
        {
            if (components)
            {
                delete components;
            }
        }

    private:
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        void InitializeComponent(void)
        {
            this->SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // Testapi
            // 
            this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(6, 13);
            this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
            this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(284, 261);
            this->Name = L"Testapi";
            this->Text = L"Testapi";
            this->Load += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Testapi::Testapi_Load);
            this->ResumeLayout(false);

        }
#pragma endregion
    private: System::Void Testapi_Load(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

        auto fileStream = std::make_shared<ostream>();

        // Open stream to output file.
        pplx::task<void> requestTask = fstream::open_ostream(U("results.html")).then([=](ostream outFile)
        {
            *fileStream = outFile;

            // Create http_client to send the request.
            http_client client(U("http://13.231.231.252:3000/api/individual_employment_setting/detail/172"));

            // Build request URI and start the request.
            //uri_builder builder(U("/search"));
            //builder.append_query(U("q"), U("cpprestsdk github"));
            return client.request(methods::GET);
        })

            // Handle response headers arriving.
            .then([=](http_response response)
        {
            printf("Received response status code:%u\n", response.status_code());

            // Write response body into the file.
            // return response.body().read_to_end(fileStream->streambuf());
            stringstreambuf buffer;
            response.body().read_to_end(buffer).get();

            //show content in console
            printf("Response body: \n %s", buffer.collection().c_str());

            //parse content into a JSON object:
            //json::value jsonvalue = json::value::parse(buffer.collection());

            return  fileStream->print(buffer.collection()); //write to file anyway
        })

            // Close the file stream.
            .then([=](size_t)
        {
            return fileStream->close();
        });

        // Wait for all the outstanding I/O to complete and handle any exceptions
        try
        {
            requestTask.wait();
        }
        catch (const std::exception &e)
        {
            printf("Error exception:%s\n", e.what());
        }

    }
    };
}

#endif /*TESTAPI_H*/
```

Comment: In vs13, CLR and std threading used to be mutually exclusive. I guess vs17 is no different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the very end of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15822678/8873508), Hans Passant gives a hint which is useful in your case. Basically, you need a separate c++ library (clr support turned off) where you wrap the `cpprest` code, link this library from your CLR project and be sure no included headers will bring `<mutex>` in.

Just an example, have a class like this, in a *restwrapper.h* header file:

```
class RestWrapper
{
public:
    void test();
};
```

In its implementation file, *restwrapper.cpp*:

```
#include "restwrapper.h"

#include <cpprest/http_client.h>
#include <cpprest/filestream.h>
#include <cpprest/json.h>

using namespace utility;                    // Common utilities like string conversions
using namespace web;                        // Common features like URIs.
using namespace web::http;                  // Common HTTP functionality
using namespace web::http::client;          // HTTP client features
using namespace concurrency::streams;       // Asynchronous streams

void RestWrapper::test()
{
    auto fileStream = std::make_shared<ostream>();

    // Open stream to output file.
    pplx::task<void> requestTask = fstream::open_ostream(U("results.html")).then([=](ostream outFile)
    {
        *fileStream = outFile;

        // Create http_client to send the request.
        http_client client(U("http://13.231.231.252:3000/api/individual_employment_setting/detail/172"));

        //etc ...
}
```

You can compile this class in a DLL (linking `cpprest` and all its related libraries) then make your CLR project link that library. In the CLR project you need to include *restwrapper.h* only, which in turn includes nothing:

```
#include <restwrapper.h>
System::Void Testapi_Load(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) 
{
    RestWrapper wrapper;
    wrapper.test();
}
```

Comment: Thanks sir, I will try it.

Comment: About the (linking cpprest and all its related libraries), do i need to manually link it in the project?

Comment: Hi sir, I'm having an "entry point" error. What entry point should i set in DLL project? In my source files i have, dllmain.cpp, MyCpprestDll.cpp, stdafx.cpp (this three are generated by IDE), and the last one that I added, RestWrapper.cpp. But if i set entry point in the properties, I get many errors.

Comment: Good morning @noyruto88. I'm sorry I cannot be of any help today, but you can make a new question out of this issue and there will be plenty of people eaging to answer it. Thanks.

Comment: Ok Sir, Thank you.

Comment: Hi Sir, do you have idea about this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49868625/http-client-of-cpprestsdk-casablanca

Comment: Hi Sir @paolo. I posted a question about japanese charaters in c++. Maybe you can help. Thank you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51204412/dealing-with-kanji-characters-in-c

Answer (score 3):

You can call a class that uses mutexes from a CLR project, what you need to do is create a normal c++ project and create classes that have the required functionality but don't expose `<mutex>` in their headers, you are then free to call these classes from your CLR project.

Answer (score -5):

Just right click your .cpp file, and under "General -> Common Language Runtime Support" select "No Common Language RunTime Support".

Simplest solution really.

Comment: it's not a solution when one needs CLR (for interacting with .NET or wrapping C# functions for example)

Comment: Yes it is, solved the same issue this way recently. In fact one is able to supply a different compiler options set for each c++ file included in project, that is - to combine pure C++ and C++/CLI source files inside one project. The next step is likely to utilize PIMPL idiom in order to make a kind of wrapper in raw C++ above problem class - so that all dangerous includes are included in c++ file. The last step is to include wrapper header in C++/CLI source file (compiled with different options). I personally had to disable C++/CLI for project and _enable_ it only for desired files.

Comment: Wondering why the down votes since the suggestion is to turn of /clr for the SINGLE .cpp file..... Do not understand why the recommendation for a completely different project is preferred...