# http_client of cpprestsdk/casablanca

Tags: c++, casablanca, cpprest-sdk

I have api `https://api.gm-system.net/api/authenticate/searchStaffs/searchText` which return a list staff.

And here is my code to access this api using `cpprestsdk` with c++.

```
auto fileStream = std::make_shared<ostream>();

    // Open stream to output file.
    pplx::task<void> requestTask = fstream::open_ostream(U("results.html")).then([=](ostream outFile)
    {
        *fileStream = outFile;

        // Create http_client to send the request.
        http_client client(U("https://api.gm-system.net/api/authenticate/searchStaffs/michael"));


        return client.request(methods::GET);
    })

        // Handle response headers arriving.
        .then([=](http_response response)
    {
       ......
    }
```

This one if fine. But with that i just manually input the `"michael" searchText`.

How can I make it that it will accept any searchText something like this.

```
void MyTest(std::string searchText)
{
..... code here

// Create http_client to send the request.
http_client client(U("https://api.gm-system.net/api/authenticate/searchStaffs/" + searchText));

return client.request(methods::GET);

..... code here
}
```

I already tried this it won't work. Some problem with 'U' macro.
From https://github.com/Microsoft/cpprestsdk/wiki/FAQ the discription of `U macro` is says:

```
The 'U' macro can be used to create a string literal of the platform type. If you are using a library causing conflicts with the 'U' macro, for example Boost.Iostreams it can be turned off by defining the macro '_TURN_OFF_PLATFORM_STRING' before including the C++ REST SDK header files.
```

If I point my cursor to `U`, the error says:

```
no operator "+" matches these operands operand types are; const wchar_t[57] + const std::string
```

I hope some can help me. Thanks.

Comment: Can you please, somehow, point me at the `http_client` class header you're using? I'm curious to see the constructor overloads.

Comment: I think we can use append or append_path? https://microsoft.github.io/cpprestsdk/classweb_1_1uri__builder.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since

> The C++ REST SDK uses a different string type dependent on the
>   platform being targeted. For example for the Windows platforms
>   utility::string_t is std::wstring using UTF-16, on Linux std::string
>   using UTF-8.

you should use the `utility::string_t` class whenever it is required and don't mix it with `std::string` or `const char *` (and use the `U` macro when in need of a literal).

In other words, your function should accept an `utility::string_t` as its `searchText` argument (instead of `std::string`):

```
void MyTest(utility::string_t searchText)
{
    http_client client(U("https://api.gm-system.net/api/authenticate/searchStaffs/") + searchText);

    // etc ...

}
```

use it like this:

```
int main()
{

    utility::string_t searchText = U("Michael");
    MyTest(searchText);

    return 0;
}
```

If the function has to be called from a platform specific context, the corresponding `std` type can be used as the passed in  argument type (i.e. use `std::wstring` on Windows):

```
std::wstring searchText = L"Michael";
MyTest(searchText);
```

Comment: Thank you, but both solution don't work. In the second solution the error says: error C2664: 'web::http::client::http_client::http_client(const web::http::client::http_client &)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>' to 'const web::uri &'.

Comment: Ok, I think I solved the mistery (I'm on linux, obviously).

Comment: Thank you sir. It solve the problem for this. But I'm calling 'MyTest()' function from my CLR project which I cannot use 'utility' there. If I will, I'll get back to the error about 'Mutex'. Is there utility-like for CLR project which uses .NET?

Comment: @noyruto88 please check my edit, I hope it works fine.

Comment: Still the same sir. Ahmm anyway I'm getting data from String ^ searchText = searchBox->Text;. Do you know what conversion do i need so that i can pass that data to MyTest(searchText)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14047414/convert-a-string-to-wstring-c

Comment: Hi Sir, maybe you can help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49933541/how-to-extract-specific-data-returned-from-webjsonvalueserialize-with-cp thank you

Comment: Hi Sir, do you have an idea about this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50406621/cpprest-with-japanese-character . Thank you.