# How to iterate through json objects with cpprest

Tags: c++, cpprest-sdk

I have a "jvalue" variable that holds a json data:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "_id": 123,
            "name": "Name 1"
        },
        {
            "_id": 124,
            "name": "Name 2"
        }  
    ],
    "success": true
}
```

This is my code that i tried:

```
auto data = jvalue.at(U("data")).at(0);
auto dataObj = data.as_object();

for (auto iterInner = dataObj.cbegin(); iterInner != dataObj.cend(); ++iterInner)
{
    auto &propertyName = iterInner->first;
    auto &propertyValue = iterInner->second;

    std::wcout << "Property: " << propertyName << ", Value: " << propertyValue << std::endl;
}
```

But it displays the first set of data only:

```
Property: _id, Value: 123
Property: name, Value: "Name 1"
```

I know I'm missing something here, but the idea won't pop up to my mind.
Maybe something like double for loop.

Can anybody share an idea to this. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Now you are iterating only over object's properties, you have to iterate over array elements too:

```
auto DataArray = jvalue.at(U("data")).as_array();

for (int i = 0; i< DataArray.size(); i++)
{
    auto data = DataArray[i];
    auto dataObj = data.as_object();

    for (auto iterInner = dataObj.cbegin(); iterInner != dataObj.cend(); ++iterInner)
    {
        auto &propertyName = iterInner->first;
        auto &propertyValue = iterInner->second;

        std::wcout << "Property: " << propertyName << ", Value: " << 
        propertyValue << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Or use iterators to iterate over array:

```
auto DataArray = jvalue.at(U("data")).as_array();

for (auto Iter = DataArray.begin(); Iter != DataArray.end(); ++Iter)
{
    auto& data = *Iter;
    auto dataObj = data.as_object();

    for (auto iterInner = dataObj.cbegin(); iterInner != dataObj.cend(); ++iterInner)
    {
        auto &propertyName = iterInner->first;
        auto &propertyValue = iterInner->second;

        std::wcout << "Property: " << propertyName << ", Value: " << 
        propertyValue << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir Alex. I tried your answer and it works but it returns data not completely, it display only 6 objects.

Comment: @noyruto88 What does DataArray.size() returns?

Comment: when i tried to std::wcout << DataArray.size() it returns 10.

Comment: Here is the output of my program: https://github.com/noyruto5/My-Concerns/issues/1

Comment: @noyruto88 Updated my answer, try to use iterators to iterate over array, hope it will help.

Comment: I think there's something wrong with the json data. In item 6 "{
            "_id": 164,
            "name": "Marvin　Superales"
        }, the space between "Marvin" and "Suparales". The code stops there. It's not a normal whitespace.

Comment: the same result sir. It stop at "Marvin" word.

Comment: @noyruto88 Try to replace that string by anything else, to check problem

Comment: I'm sorry sir, I do not have the right to change the data, I was just able to get the result of the api. Anyway, thank you very much.

Comment: It's okay now sir. I requested someone to update the name in database. Thank you.

Comment: @noyruto88 You have an IDEOGRAPHIC SPACE(%u3000) in that place. `"Marvin　Superales" => %22Marvin%u3000Superales%22`. But it has to be `%20` as simple space. `"Charlene Marie C. Buena"=>%22Charlene%20Marie%20C.%20Buena%22`

Comment: Ahh.. I see. Thank you.