# cpprest with japanese character?

Tags: c++, cpprest-sdk, cjk

The following code:

```
auto nullValue = json::value::null();
std::string searchText = conversions::to_utf8string("michael");
make_request(client, methods::GET, nullValue, searchText);
```

Returns the json data:

```
{"data":[
  {
    "_id":172,"name":"Michael Edano","profile_picture":null
  }],
  "success":true
}
```

But if i put Japanese string:

```
auto nullValue = json::value::null();
std::string searchText = conversions::to_utf8string("北島 美奈");
make_request(client, methods::GET, nullValue, searchText);
```

The output is:

```
provided uri is invalid: /api/authenticate/searchStaffs/?? ??
```

But the expected output is:

```
{"data":[{"_id":12,"name":"北島 美奈","profile_picture":null}],"success":true}
```

**What is the cause of this?**

Comment: It would be helpful if you showed the code of makeRequest.

Comment: Here's the complete code: https://github.com/noyruto5/My-Concerns/issues/3

Answer (score 0):

all you need to do is

```
auto nullValue = json::value::null();
std::wstring searchText =L"北島 美奈";
make_request(client, methods::GET, nullValue, searchText);
```

hopefully it helps